# trying to understand preg_replace's behavior on large strings

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
$str = str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024);
//$str = str_repeat('a', 1024);
$temp = preg_replace('#.*?^-+[^-]+-+[\r\n ]*$#ms', '', $str, 1);

echo strlen($temp);
```

With `str_repeat('a', 1024)` the length of `$temp` is 1024 but with `str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024)` the length of `$temp` is 0.

I'm running PHP 7.4.3.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Should see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php.

Comment: _With str_repeat('a', 1024) the length of $temp is 1024 but with str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024) the length of $temp is 0_ not really. https://3v4l.org/1b4SE

Comment: It has obviously something to do with preg_replace.

Comment: *looks* like you're hitting a [PCRE backtrack limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit): https://3v4l.org/02cQ8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually got an error

```
Process exited with code 137
```

on this function:

```
$temp = preg_replace('#.*?^-+[^-]+-+[\r\n ]*$#ms', '', $str, 1);
```

and that ends up the $str to be `NULL` and automatically your `strlen($temp);` is actually `strlen(NULL);` which gives you `0`.

---

1024 * 1024 = 1048576

and the default setting in php.ini for pcre.backtrack_limit is 1000000

To fix that problem change this setting inside php.ni file

```
pcre.backtrack_limit=1048577
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an with char limit set in php.ini to handle regular expressions. By default it will be **100000**. The given string length 1024 * 1024 = **1048576** exceeds the limit. change

```
pcre.backtrack_limit=1048577
```

in php.ini and restart the apache it will work